# DSUM is adding up previous rows to new row

Tags: google-sheets

So I have 'Orders' that simplified for this example look like this

| OId | Total |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |

I also have 'Line Items' sheet that look like this

| IId | OId | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 20 |
| 3 | 2 | 12 |
| 4 | 2 | 10 |

Now I'm trying to use DSUM on Orders sheet to sum up Total value of Line Items per order

I expect to get this:

| OId | Total |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 22 |

What I get is this:

| OId | Total |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 52 |

The formula on Order sheet in column Total I'm using is =DSUM('Line items'!A:B, 'Total', $A$1:A2)

Why am I getting sum of previous rows instead of just ones filtered by the Order Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=DSUM('Line items'!A:C, "Total",{"OId";E1})
```

[image]

Comment: This approach with {} works. Ty.